# How to back up/export the work profile?

Tags: backup

My phone is rooted: I can use [OandbackupX](https://github.com/machiav3lli/oandbackupx) to back up apps (APKs) with their data and TWRP to create recovery images, but the work profile appears to lack root rights and I have no idea how to grab the app data from there.

[Shelter](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.typeblog.shelter/)'s app-cloning feature doesn't transfer app data based on my experience, only reinstalls apparently.

Comment: Termux with `su` might be an option?

Comment: I wasn't able to find when Android introduced the work profiles, but I'm on Android 9 if this makes a difference.

Comment: `/data/users/` has apps' data from all the users. Use a command line utility such as `tar` to backup app data. Make sure to preserve permissions for the app directory and files (search web to get examples). Saved the APKs too if you don't have them and can't get them from elsewhere anymore.

Comment: @Firelord I see, my work profile was called `10`.